# How to charge .txt file as a parameter in function Phyton

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a function that validates some emails, the thing is I do not know how to charge the data into Python so I can operate with it.  Also i do not know how to iterate between different emails so I can choose whether they are correct or not.
The data format is .txt and the head is like this

```
rmc_farla@yahoo.com
policies2020@live.com
boomzilla@aol.com
wonderkid@*1956*.com
wilsonpm@att.net
yzheng@comcast.net
imightb@sbcglobal.net
roesch@verizon.net
etc...
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Break the problem into smaller pieces. It sounds like the first thing you need to learn is how to open a file and read lines from it. I suggest you use google to search for a tutorial that shows how to do this.

Comment: You should start with the very basics. Look up how to read a file in Python, look up how iteration works, and read about lists and dictionaries. This is such a simple example that everything you're asking to do has been answered many times already. To give you the answer would just be rehashing info that's already widely available and wouldn't be useful to anyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to input the data from a text file, see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp) tutorial, about reading data.

To iterate between emails (strings), for example, use a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).